# Can I store objects from android SDK like Location?

Tags: android, realm

Can I store objects from android SDK like Location in realm? If so, how can I do it? I am getting this error message `Error:(14, 8) error: Type android.location.Location of field location is not supported` or what could be a workaround to save a location?

Comment: You can probably serialise the object by json that will give you the string that you can store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm can only store classes that extends RealmObject, so it is not possible to save the `android.location.Location` class directly.

If you require the android `Location` class for some other API I would create my own Realm Location class that are able to convert it's representation, like so:

```
public class MyLocation extends RealmObject {

  // Duplicate all parameters required to initialise a android Location 
  private double longitude;
  private double latitude;
  ...

  // Public static method for converting object to android Location
  public static android.location.Location getLocation(MyLocation loc) {
    Location location = new Location("Realm");
    // Set all relevant location parameters
    return location;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it, so can static methods be written on RealmObjects? I thought setters and getters only.

Comment: Yes, static fields and methods are also allowed.

Comment: One last question, this will be the final implementations on the realm release or do you are planning to support another no realm objects?

Comment: We are still considering adding native support for other classes, eg. BigDecimal and URL, but all classes we add support for has to work on other platforms as well so we most likely won't add support for advanced classes like Android Location.